# Xamarin Essentials Media Picker Keeps Crashing My App - No Exception or erros

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.essentials

I built a Xamarin App: Android, and am trying to allow the user to be able to set an avatar. using Xamarin Essentials Media Picker I am trying to either capture an image or select one. But each time the application runs either method, it works then crashes the app before an image is selected or captures. The funny thing is it sometimes works but hardly ever.

I tried a lot of ways to figure out what is going on but without an actual error to work with, I am getting nowhere.

I am using the MVVM design pattern.
My Code:

```
    private async Task TakePicture()
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.PickPhotoAsync(); 
            if (photo != null)
            {
                await App.UserManager.UpdateAvatarAsync(photo);
                RenderImages();
            }
        }
        catch (global::System.Exception ex)
        {
            await AppShell.Current.DisplayAlert("Oops", "Something went wrong and its not your fault", "Okay");
        }

    }
```

Comment: what does the device log show?  Have you tried a crash reporting service like raygun.io or appcenter.ms?  Are you properly checking for permissions?

Comment: @Jason - Permissions I think I have properly covered. Won't lie I am fairly new to Xamarin so I have not tried crash reporting services. I think I will start now by checking first the device log as you suggesting.

Comment: @Jason the device log is not showing anything.

Comment: The code seems okay. Have you try to test on other device? Does it crash as the same?

Comment: @SechabaMotaung I provide two ways to pick photo. You could check it.

Comment: Were you able to figure out what was causing the crash? I’m having the same issue in my Xamarin Forms app with the latest version of Xamarin Essentials.

Comment: @Sam, No not really. The problem was one that stopped at times. Eventually, I stopped working on the project for other reasons. Try the first answer below.

Comment: Same issue here.  Debugging VS 2022 using an Android 12 Samsung s21 device produced this Android lang exception "Canvas trying to draw too large(256576512bytes) bitmap".  Capturing normal images works as expected.  However, this error was triggered using a 3:4 64MP image.  Seems higher quality images are the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the ways below to piack the photo.

**1. Use the `Xam.Plugin.Media`.** You could install from the NuGet. Do not forget to checkthe location you save the photos and ask for the runtime permission.

The code below shows how to pick the photo from Camera and set to the image control.

```
  pickPhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
  {
    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsPickPhotoSupported)
    {
      DisplayAlert("Photos Not Supported", ":( Permission not granted to photos.", "OK");
      return;
    }
     var file = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PickMediaOptions
                  {
                      PhotoSize =  Plugin.Media.Abstractions.PhotoSize.Medium,
                
                  });


    if (file == null)
      return;

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
      var stream = file.GetStream();
      file.Dispose();
      return stream;
    });
  };
```

[image]

**2. Use the dependency service.**

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(PhotoPickerService))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.Droid
{
public class PhotoPickerService : IPhotoPickerService
{
    public Task<Stream> GetImageStreamAsync()
    {
        // Define the Intent for getting images
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.SetType("image/*");
        intent.SetAction(Intent.ActionGetContent);

        // Start the picture-picker activity (resumes in MainActivity.cs)
        MainActivity.Instance.StartActivityForResult(
            Intent.CreateChooser(intent, "Select Photo"),
            MainActivity.PickImageId);

        // Save the TaskCompletionSource object as a MainActivity property
        MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<Stream>();

        // Return Task object
        return MainActivity.Instance.PickImageTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }
}
}
```

[image]

You could download the source file from the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/dependencyservice/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I Will try and implement it as soon as I can and give you feedback. For now, I had to move on real quick as the project is time-sensitive.

Comment: This is no longer possible in MAUI 8